# Ionic app working fine in browser but not in phone

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I have an Ionic app which has the firebase as a backend. App working fine with ionic serve --lab but when i build this app with phonegap build, .apk file installs and open its static pages correctly but when i click on any of the component which accesses the firebase it doesn't work then. Why this is happening? How to debug then?

Comment: Please add some code examples and some debug logs, otherwise we will be unable to figure out your problem. If you run the Android app using Android Studio, you should be able to get some logs. Did you test whether it works in an emulator using `ionic emulate android`?

Comment: Thanks @dexter, actually i have tried testing my app on phonegap serve and ionic serve it is working flawless but it's apk build not working. And it is giving no error